# 3D кнопка, проблема с реализацией border

Tags: html, css, css3, css-animation

Как можно реализовать бордер как показан на картинке ниже? Толкового ничего в голову не лезет

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@600&display=swap");

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 21px;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e37373;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: -8px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #e37373;
    transform: skewX(45deg);
}

.button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -8px;
    bottom: -4px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e37373;
    transform: skewY(45deg);
}
```

```html
    <button class="button" type="button" >Press me!</button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно примерно вот так:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@600&display=swap");

.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 21px;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.3;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #e37373;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: all 0.25s;
    border: 2px solid #114424;
}

.button::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 3.5px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #114424 50%, #e37373 50%);
    background-size: 7px 100%;
    transform: translateY(100%) skewX(45deg);
    border: 2px solid #114424;
}

.button::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -7.5px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #114424 50%, #e37373 50%);
    background-size: 100% 7px;
    background-position: 10px;
    transform: translateX(100%) skewY(45deg);
    border: 2px solid #114424;
}


/* переход состояния :active */

.button::before,
.button::after { transition: all 0.25s; }

.button:active {
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 3px), calc(-50% + 3px));
}

.button:active::before {
  transform: translate(-1.5%, 90%) skewX(47deg) scaleY(0.6);
}

.button:active::after {
  transform: translate(90%, -2.5%) skewY(47deg) scaleX(0.6);
}
```

```html
<button class="button" type="button" >Press me!</button>
```

Comment: У меня в Chrome (вер.91 для линупс) края сходились слегка неровно с оригинальными стилями, смещались буквально на пиксель - в правке попытался сохранить это смещение чтобы не поломать, но мог нечаянно сдвинуть (сорри если придется откатывать правку).

Comment: @yar85 А вот на винде наоборот смещается теперь) В любом случае, это пример реализации, а не готовое решение. Такие мелочи уже стоит дорабатывать автору вопроса на конкретном проекте под его условия.

Comment: Да ну.. Вы психи.. В хорошем плане)